# What is wrong in saying that the map $F:\mathbb{S}^1 \times I \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $F(z,t)=z^{t+1}$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb{S}^1$ be the unit circle of complex plane and $f,g:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ be two maps defined by $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=z^2$. What is wrong in saying that the map $F:\mathbb{S}^1 \times I \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $F(z,t)=z^{t+1}$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$?

---

Can someone tell me please what is wrong ?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

What is $F(x,\frac{1}{2})$? In particular, will this be a function that is continuous on $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Raising a complex number to a non-integer power is [more complicated than you're realizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Computation_of_ab_where_both_a_and_b_are_complex). The "function" $z^{t}$ is really multivalued when $t\notin\mathbb{Z}$, and even after choosing a branch, it won't be continuous.

Comment: Could you say more about what's wrong with continuity of $z^t$?  I know the proof for no existence of such homotopy when we model unit circle maps as $2\pi$- periodic maps of $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm interested in purely complex setting of this question.

Comment: @Evgeny: Remember a branch for the logarithm can only be continuously chosen on a simply connected region.